# An example of $K(G,1)$ in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

A $K(G,1)$ space is a path-connected topological space $X$ with contractible universal cover and 
$$
\pi_1(X)=G.
$$
I am reading about $K(G,1)$ spaces in [Hatcher's textbook](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) and I don't understand Example 1B.7.

Hatcher is showing how to construct a $K(G,1)$ for an arbitrary group $G$. He defines the $\Delta$-complex $EG$ whose $n$-simplices are the ordered $(n+1)$-tuples $[g_0,..., g_n]$ of elements of $G$. But in chapter 2 he defines $n$-simplices as certain subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$. How is it possible to just take arbitrary ordered subsets of the group $G$ and why can we think of them as convex hulls in some Euclidean space?

Comment: This is the notion of an abstract [simplicial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex). Given any simplicial complex, we can form its geometric realization; the geometric realization of the simplicial complex he constructs is the space you're looking for. Searching for these keywords should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there some sort of implicit ordering of the group $G$ which passes to the corresponding ordering of the vertices of $EG$?

Comment: Nope. That's a good point, though - that's why we use *all* $(n+1)$-tuples [$g_0, \dots, g_n]$. In particular, $[a,b]$ is a $1$-simplex *as is* $[b,a]$.

Comment: Do we also allow repetitions? Is $[a,a]$ a valid 1-simplex?

Comment: Aye.${}{}{}{}{}$